# Restore Complete Deleted Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have done something terrible. I deleted my google drive folder from my local disk and accidentally open google drive shortcut which synced everything from local drive to google drive and deleted everything from my google drive that contains my years of hard work. Many lessons learnt but right now can anyone tell me that is there any way to get back my google drive completely?

Comment: logon to drive.gogle.com and see if the deleted files are still in your Trash folder

Comment: Yup that's what I did. Folders were empty there that made me feel worried but when I restored them I got my data back. Now I should start thinking of regular backups of my google drive.

Comment: I think Google Drive is the backup plan, so if you're planning to backup the Google Drive files themselves, it would help if you have a second copy stored somewhere else like a second Google Drive account, an external drive, another cloud storage(AWS, One Drive), etc.